# ASP.NET MVC Частичное представление и jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Представление List.cshtml отображает список товаров. Строки списка формируются частичным представлением. Упрощенно это можно описать следующими блоками кода:

List.cshtml:

```
@model IEnumerable<Product>

@foreach (var p in Model)
{
    Html.RenderPartial("ProductSummary", p)
}
```

ProductSummary.cshtml:

```
@model Product

<div class="item">
    @Model.name
     <input type="submit" value="Details" id="DetailButton"/>
    <textarea class="details" id="details">
        @Model.details
    </textarea>
</div>
```

Количество строк на странице может быть произвольным но для конкретики возьмем 20

Есть скрипт

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#DetailButton").click(function () {
        $("#details").toggle();
    });
});
```

Делает видимым/невидимым тесктовый блок только в первом товаре

Если меняю $("#details") на $(".details") видимость изменяется для всех 20ти текстовых полей.

Помогите, пожалуйста, написать скрипт который бы изменял видимость текстовой зоны в каждом товаре по нажатию кнопки DetailButton в этом же товаре

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@model Product

<div class="item">
    @Model.name
    <input type="button" value="Details" class="DetailButton"/>
    <textarea class="details" class="details">
        @Model.details
    </textarea>
</div>
```

js:

```
jQuery(function ($){
   $(document).on('click', '.DetailButton', function (){
       $(this).closest('.item').find('.details').toggle();
   });
});
```

Comment: Спасибо! Ваш скрипт замечательно справился с задачей. К сожалению не могу поставить лайк т.к. мало репутации

Comment: >К сожалению не могу поставить лайк т.к. мало репутации

ну так примите ответ тогда

Answer (score -1):

Если вы в модели передаете еще и уникальный id товара тогда можно это сделать так:
ProductSummary.cshtml

```
@model Product

<div class="item">
    @Model.name
    <input type="button" value="Details" onclick="ShowDetails(@(Model.Id)); return false;"/>
    <textarea class="details" id="details@(Model.Id)">
        @Model.details
    </textarea>
</div>
```

скрипт:

```
function ShowDetails(id){
    $('#details' + id).toggle();
}
```

Comment: Человек, который поставил минус, где конструктивная критика ? Или минус просто так ?

Comment: Я минус не ставил, но могу сказать что VisualStudio выдает ошибку на onclick="ShowDetails(@(Model.Id));
ошибка синтаксиса....

Comment: Да, VisualStudio показывает что есть ошибка синтаксиса, однако все правильно отрендерится и будет работать. Это скорее всего баг студии.